# Why isn't button working? (checking console.log)

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

Using framework7, I would like to create a cart view on my application following you-tube tutorial.

I checked that the js file is properly called but the button is not working. If I click the button, `console.log('clicked')` should be displayed, but It doesn't work.

https://github.com/hahmmj/IPP20201_HALFSTACK

Javascript code:

```
console.log("storejs")

window.onload = () => {
var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger');
console.log(removeCartItemButtons)
for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++){
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log('clicked')
    })
}
}
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It seems to work for me. On a blank page I put the JS given into `<script>` element and add two buttons to the body with class `btn-danger`. When I click on them I get the console log as expected

Comment: Maybe ensure there are no transparent elements covering the buttons

Comment: Thanks @Dcdanny,

The problem is that other button is working and seems to be clicked properly.

But when i click this button to remove articles (with class name btn-danger), It looks like other place is clicked (even if i clicked the button)

Answer (score -1):

This looks similar to this: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) which has several solutions to your problem.

Essentially as the function within `addEventListener` is asynchronous, it only runs after the loop has completed.